# Quadcopter flight controller - black smoke?

Tags: quadcopter

I bought a qx95 and after a few flights, maybe 3, there was black smoke that fizzled out of the what looks like the flight controller. And since then, anytime I give throttle - the fpv video feed cuts signal.

I'm assuming what I fizzled was some sort of limiter / power converter for the video?

My question is - what do I need to replace? Was that the flight controller or camera? Any thoughts on what I need to replace or repair?

Comment: What flight controller are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Double check whether it was the flight controller that burnt out, if it was the flight controller, then you should clearly see a difference in flight.

Also, throttle input and the fpv video aren't related unless you are using a power distribution board of some sort that can't take the high voltages or amperage. Check if all the wires and PCBs are ok.

Comment: At office now. I will check board for markings. I'm thinking it was a limiter for voltage maybe. Since the fpv video cut is directly related to the throttle. And I just need to replace something so hoping it's the board. Thanks for your input sids I will check board tonight

Comment: No worries... @joepwn

Comment: Limiter of what voltage? The "voltage" to the motor or to the fpv part or flight controller?

Comment: I meant the voltage to the power distribution board, if you don't know what is is google it. If you give it too much volts, then it smokes out. If you're using the power distribution board to power your fav gear, then check it

Answer (score 1):

If the quad is a manufactured model, not a home built one, then the power would follow the same grouping I would take a look at the regulator circuit as it sounds that the voltage is dropping due the amp supply not being great enough. I would assume controller board being that it sounds like the regulator cooked and that's where it would be located.